# Flutter : border radius not working on icon

Tags: image, flutter, dart, icons, flutter-layout

I am trying to convert this circular icon to the one below but when I use borderRadius it doesn't change anything. What should I do?
[image]

to this :

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
class IconTrangChu {
  Border border;
  BorderRadius borderRadius;
  Icon icon;
  int numOfItems;
  String title;
  Color colorIcon;
  String routes;

  IconTrangChu({
    this.colorIcon,
    this.icon,
    this.numOfItems,
    this.title,
    this.routes,
    this.border,
    this.borderRadius,
  });
}

List<IconTrangChu> listIconTrangChus = [
  IconTrangChu(
    title: "",
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.assessment,
      size: 30.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    numOfItems: 3,
    colorIcon: Color(0XFFB5CCFA),
    routes: 'xemdiem',
  ),
]
```

Comment: Please post your class code for  `IconTrangChu`

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the border radius :

`borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),`

Comment: What happens when you change it ? 
And what is the IconTrangChu widget ?

Comment: IconTranChu is a List

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to create below same the picture ?

[image]

If yes ? Then you can try

```
 Container(
    width: 28,
    height: 28,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.25), // border color
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), // border width
      child: Container( // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.blue, // inner circle color
        ),
        child: Container(), // inner content
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

If you no need border of circular container ? Then remove top decoration of parent container. I hope solve your problem. if not? please comment . I will try to another solution

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. I don't want my icon to be circle. I want it to be the second picture which i have post up there.